# Blank Map Screen Open while using Google Maps Api v2

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to use Google Maps Api V2 and following all the steps in [Android Google Maps Article](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html)

But after all steps, code is executed on my glaxy young with android 2.36 but blank map screen is displayed

My main activity code is

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.showmapactivity_layout);
FragmentManager myFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
SupportMapFragment mySupportMapFragment 
 = (SupportMapFragment)myFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
map = mySupportMapFragment.getMap();

//map = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
Marker hamburg = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(HAMBURG)
    .title("Hamburg"));
Marker kiel = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(KIEL)
    .title("Kiel")
    .snippet("Kiel is cool")
    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
        .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher)));

// Move the camera instantly to hamburg with a zoom of 15.
map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(HAMBURG, 15));

// Zoom in, animating the camera.
map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);
}
```

Maifestfile code is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.archifiles.pointpakistan"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="10" />

<permission
    android:name="com.archifiles.pointpakistan.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.archifiles.pointpakistan.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.archifiles.pointpakistan.SplashScreenActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".POIActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".ShowMapActivity"></activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyDe_pk7x98rwq2GTkaaUUv0K0Yri3TRPUA" />

    <uses-library  
   android:name="com.google.android.maps"  
   android:required="true" /> 

</application>
```

Layout file code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

No log traces are available in log cat.

Comment: pls post your layout xml file also.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you used `SupportMapFragment`. Like

```
SupportMapFragment gm;

  gm = ((SupportMapFragment)(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))).getMap();
```

So in xml file also you must use like this

```
      <fragment  
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
      />
```

Hope it will work.

Remove this below line in your manifest

```
<uses-library  
 android:name="com.google.android.maps"  
 android:required="true" />
```

Comment: Dear Shadow thanks for your response. Layout file code added, already using android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"

Comment: whether you used signed or unsigned apk to check in device? @MuhammadImran

Answer (score 0):

This problem happen because of invalid key,generate a valid key and add your current package name at the end of the hashkey.

> To get the key:
>
> ```
> In the left navigation bar, click API Access.
> In the resulting page, click Create New Android Key....
>
> In the resulting dialog, enter the SHA-1 fingerprint, then a semicolon, then your application's package name. For example:
>
> BB:0D:AC:74:D3:21:E1:43:67:71:9B:62:91:AF:A1:66:6E:44:5D:75;com.example.android.mapexample
>
> The Google APIs Console responds by displaying Key for Android apps (with certificates) followed by a forty-character API key, for
> ```
>
> example:
>
> ```
> AIzaSyBdVl-cTICSwYKrZ95SuvNw7dbMuDt1KG0
>
> Copy this key value. You will use it in the next step.
> ```

check this url.

```
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#obtaining_an_api_key
```